# How to exec code after uvicorn.run() in python socketio server?

Tags: python, socket.io, async-await, uvicorn

I need to run some code after waking up a webserver. In the example it's "`start_my_thing()`".

```
import asyncio
import sys

import uvicorn

import socketio

@sio.on('connect')
async def test_connect(sid, environ):
    pass

app = socketio.ASGIApp(sio, static_files={
    '/': 'app.html',
    '/static/': 'static/',
})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
    start_my_thing()
```

The line with `start_my_thing()` will never be reached out because `uvicorn.run()` starts infinite loop.

But is there any trick to run some code when a webserver is already accessible?

Comment: I think you can solve it by running uvicorn.run in multithread.